# Can't access control or click event within placeholder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create a custom Panel-Expander-Module. The Expander works, but if I try to cut and copy my old code into the placeholders, VS2015 tells me that there are some errors.

1. Error: "lstXYZ" not declared it may be inaccessible due to its protection level
2. Error: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types

Here is a code example:

The Usercontrol which holds the Placeholders for the panels (panelExpander.ascx):

```
<%-- Begin Panel Wrapper --%>
<div  id="panelContainer" class="Panel collapseable slim" runat="server">
    
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPanelClosed" runat="server" Value=""></asp:HiddenField>
    
    <%-- Begin Panel Header --%>
    <div class="panel-header PanelHeader">
        <span><asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phPanelHeader" /></span>
        <div class="PanelToggleIcon">
            <img  id="panelToggleIcon" src="" runat="server">
        </div>
    </div>
    <%-- End Panel Header --%>

    <%-- Begin Panel Content --%>
    <div id="panelContentContainer" class="panel-content" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phPanelContent" />
    </div>
    <%-- End Panel Content --%>
</div>
<%-- End Panel Wrapper --%>
```

In the panelExpander.vb:

```
        ''' <summary>
        ''' ***
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <returns></returns>
        <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
        Public Property PanelHeader As ITemplate

        ''' <summary>
        ''' ***
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <returns></returns>
        <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
        Public Property PanelContent As ITemplate

        ''' <summary>
        ''' ***
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="sender">sender</param>
        ''' <param name="e">event Arguments</param>
        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Me.Initialize() 'setting some classes etc nothing special

            If (IsPostBack) Then
                'do stuff
            End If

        End Sub
```

The code above is working fine. If I feed it with nothing special like:

```
<%-- Loaded Usercontrol with placeholders --%>
<uc:PanelExpander runat="server">
    <%--Panel header--%>
    <PanelHeader>
        <p>Header Text</p>
    </PanelHeader>

    <%--Panel content--%>
    <PanelContent>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr...</p>
    </PanelContent>
</uc:PanelExpander>
```

The problem is caused here in MyEditMask.ascx and MyEditMask.vb:

```
<%@ Register Src="...panelExpander.ascx" TagName="PanelExpander" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<uc:PanelExpander runat="server">
    <panelheader>
        <%-- Nothign happens here, works fine. --%>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeader" Text="Header"></asp:Label>
    </panelheader>

    <panelcontent>
        <%-- seems ok in ascx but in codebehin it throws errors --%>
         <asp:ListBox ID="lstAvailable" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"
         DataTextField="CAL_NAME" DataValueField="CAL_ID" Rows="10" CssClass="some classes"></asp:ListBox>

        <%-- seems ok in ascx but in codebehin it throws errors --%>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" Text="Add >> " class="DefaultButton qb-default" />

    </panelcontent>
</uc:PanelExpander>
```

In MyEditMask.vb (where the errors are):

```
''' <summary>
''' ****
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub FillListBox()

    'Do stuff

    ' Can't access lstAvailable 
    '-> "lstAvailable" not declared it may be inaccessible due to its protection level
    lstAvailable.Items.Clear()

    'Do Stuff

End Sub


''' <summary>
''' ***
''' </summary>
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    'btnAdd throws error 
    '-> Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the 
    'containing type or one of its base types


    'Do Stuff

End Sub
```

It feels a little bit strange because the controls disappear in the designer.vb too for some reason. This all worked before I used any placeholder. I've got the feeling that the controls which I copy into the placeholders are gone from the view of my "MyEditMask.vb and MyEditMask.ascx". Why could this be?

Comment: This is happening because lstAvailable and btnAdd are inside of another control... Try adding ClientIDMode="Static" to either the Page declaration or the list view and button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright! I've found a solution. Special thanks to @Mych!

**I've changed this:**

```
<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
Public Property PanelContent As ITemplate
```

**To this:**

```
<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
<TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Multiple)>
Public Property PanelContent As ITemplate
```

Then I was able to access the controls in MyEditMask. There was just one thing missing. I was able to access the controls but they were set to nothing. Mych was suggesting that I use "[FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" Method. With that it was finally done.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do one of the following...

Add ClientIDMode to page declaration

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="YourPage.aspx.vb"
    ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

Or add ClientIDMode to the controls

```
<panelcontent>
    <%-- seems ok in ascx but in codebehin it throws errors --%>
     <asp:ListBox ID="lstAvailable" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" SelectionMode="Multiple"
     DataTextField="CAL_NAME" DataValueField="CAL_ID" Rows="10" CssClass="some classes"></asp:ListBox>

    <%-- seems ok in ascx but in codebehin it throws errors --%>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Add >> " class="DefaultButton qb-default" />

</panelcontent>
```

This should allow your code to identify the controls by their id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried what you suggested me to do. Still I get the same error... It does not matter if the ClientIDMode is set to static on the control or either of the pages or on all at the same time. I don't know what to do anymore, this project is making me crazy! EDIT: If I put the Listbox outside of the panelcontent tag but still inside my panelexpander, it is working...

Comment: This sometimes happens. You are going to need to 'mine' for the control using findControl see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx.... Basically start from something you can find and then iterate through child controls and then possible child of child controls